# Clang MacOs over command line does not work

Tags: c++, macos

I am fairly new to both MacOs and C++ and have a problem which is similar to the one described here but also no solution I find in the Internet works.

['fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found' error with the new macos 11.3 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303146/fatal-error-wchar-h-file-not-found-error-with-the-new-macos-11-3-update)

If I try to compile the most simple c++ program on my machine via command line it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Since it used to work I probably broke something but don't know what

The simple test command I use is the following

```
 clang -v --target=arm64   helloworld.cpp
```

Which results in a iostream not found error

if I now include the xcode include directory via

```
clang -v --target=arm64  -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ helloworld.cpp
```

The iostream error disappears and I get a wchar.h not found error

I removed xcode completely and reinstalled it but this seems to not help also does it not make a difference if I use clang or clang++.

With Clion and cmake it works but I do not know why

xcode-select version 2392

/usr/bin/clang

```
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

locate iostream.h

```
`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/include/glib-2.0/gio/gfileiostream.h
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/include/glib-2.0/gio/giostream.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_iostream.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/iostreams/detail/iostream.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/math/cstdfloat/cstdfloat_iostream.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/nowide/iostream.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/typeof/std/iostream.hpp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0/gio/gfileiostream.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0/gio/giostream.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.2/include/glib-2.0/gio/gsimpleiostream.h
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `clang++` for C++?

Comment: Yes , but this is mentioned that it does not work with both

Comment: Try `clang++ --target=arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0 helloworld.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar troubles building clang + llvm, then trying to use the newly built clang via

`./build/bin/clang -std=c++20 <my_file>`

gave me a

`fatal error: 'iostream' file not found`

What fixed it was if I compiled with the following instead:

`./build/bin/clang -std=c++20 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk <my_file>`

The fix largely comes from https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/issues/191#issuecomment-556983460 and the discussion there